# RoR: How to get lat and lng using geokit-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails, geokit

I want to display a google maps centered at the user's location. I am willing to use `gmaps4rails` and `geokit-rails` gems, because I guess those are the best ones.

What I have so far is the map initialization:

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers([
      {
        "lat": 0,
        "lng": 0,
        "picture": {
          "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
          "width":  36,
          "height": 36
        },
        "infowindow": "hello!"
      }
    ]);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
});
</script>
```

which works fine. Now the problem is to get the latitude and longitud based on user IP. This is what I am trying, but I am getting no result. In the controller I try to get the location using geokit gem, but it fails:

```
def view
  @location = IpGeocoder.geocode('181.169.135.95') #I know here I should use `request.remote_ip`, but as I am on localhost I can't
end
```

I got this from [geokit github](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails), but it is not working.

> You can obtain the location for an IP at any time using the geocoder
>   as in the following example:
>
> location = IpGeocoder.geocode('12.215.42.19')
>
> where Location is a GeoLoc instance containing the latitude, longitude, city, state, and country code. Also, the success value is true.

I am getting the following error: `uninitialized constant WineryController::IpGeocoder`. Can anyone explain me what does this mean, and how to go ahead? I suspect this might be something really stupid, but I am still a novice in rails.

Comment: try `@location = ::IpGeocoder.geocode('181.169.135.95')`

Comment: @BradWerth I tried that and I got `uninitialized constant IpGeocoder`

Comment: It sounds like you're missing a require

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Rails 3 with Geokit-rails3 location gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244039/using-rails-3-with-geokit-rails3-location-gem)

Comment: @BradWerth Thanks! That other post helped me out. Now I have another problem, I call `@location.lat` and `@location.lng` in my view and it just returns an empty string. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, not sure - probably better to start a new question for that one...

Comment: You might consider playing around with it in the console...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Auto-geocode the user's ip address and store in the session.
  geocode_ip_address
  def geokit
    @location = session[:geo_location]  # @location is a GeoLoc instance.
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can display the IP address by accessing the values of the hash:

```
<%= [@location['lat'],@location['lng']] %>
```

The key lesson here is that a Ruby session is a hash data-type. Consequently, the values of the hash must be retrieved by calling the hash key, such as `@location['lat']` and `@location['lng']`.

More info: [Ruby - getting value of hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676531/ruby-getting-value-of-hash)